# How to refresh synchronized data extension to see new fields?

Tags: fields, dataextensions, refresh

Some new fields were added in Salesforce and I'd like to access them in an Exact Target synchronized data extension but they aren't there.  Is there a way to refresh the synchronized data extension so these new fields are available?  The answer to this alludes me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out.  Go to Contact Builder --> Data Sources --> Synchronized --> Contacts.  Find the data extension, click edit fields, find the new field that was added in salesforce, check the box next to it and save.

That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Under Contact Builder --> Data Sources --> Syncronized --> Contacts
You'll see a trickle sync icon on the top right .. see the screenshot below   -
[image]

Comment: Actually, this just refreshes the data, not the fields.